# Para que serve o AuthContext.Provider?

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Me deparei com a seguinte linha de código e estou querendo saber o que o AuthContext.Provider faz com esses values o children

```
 <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signIn, user, logOut, techs, setTechs }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso faz com que os filhos desse provider consigam ter acesso aos dados que ele está passando no value. Isso é uma forma de compartilhar estados pela aplicação sem ter quer ficar passando via props e evitar o [prop drilling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-prop-drilling-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

Em qualquer filho dessa tag você poderia usar algo como

```
const { user } = useAuth()
```

e ter acesso aos dados do usuário.

O children seria literalmente a tag filha em relação ao provider. Seria algo mais ou menos assim

```
<AuthProvider>
  <App />
</AuthProvider>
```

Nesse caso a Tag App e todos os filhos subsequentes dela podem ter acesso ao contexto `AuthContext`

Caso queira se aprofundar mais [use context](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)